# switch and case statement is not working after updating from Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, switch-statement, case

I am trying to make a stock app using Swift but I am having a problem with a switch and case statement.  It is giving me an error where it wants me to add a question mark to the case so it will read case ?1 instead of case 1 and when I do this it gives me 3 errors saying Expected Pattern, expected expression and expected ':' after 'case'.  Any help would be great.

```
func timeLabelsForTimeFrame(_ range: ChartTimeRange) -> [String] {

    switch range {
    case .oneDay:
        return ["9:30am", "10", "11", "12pm", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
    case .fiveDays:

        let weekday = (Calendar(identifier: 
Calendar.Identifier.gregorian) as NSCalendar).components(.weekday, 
from: Date()).weekday
        switch weekday {
        case 1:
        return ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
        case 2:
        return ["Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Mon"]
        case 3:
        return ["Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Mon", "Tues"]
        case 4:
        return ["Thu", "Fri", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed"]
        case 5:
        return ["Fri", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu"]
        case 6:
        return ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
        case 7:
        return ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
        default: ()
        }
    case .tenDays:
        let weekday = (Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian) as NSCalendar).components(.weekday, from: Date()).weekday
        switch weekday {
        //sunday
        case 1:
        return ["Mon", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Wed", "Fri"]
        case 2:
        return ["Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon"]
        case 3:
        return ["Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Wed", "Fri", "Tues"]
        case 4:
        return ["Fri", "Mon", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Wed"]
        case 5:
        return ["Wed", "Mon", "Wed", "Fri", "Tues", "Thu"]
        case 6:
        return ["Mon", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Wed", "Fri"]
        //saturday
        case 7:
        return ["Mon", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Wed", "Fri"]
        default: ()
        }
    case .oneMonth:

        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "dd MMM"
        let offset = Double(-6*24*60*60)
        let start = Date()
        let fifthString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset))
        let fourthString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 2))
        let thirdString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 3))
        let secondString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 4))
        let firstString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 5))

        return[firstString, secondString, thirdString, fourthString, fifthString, ""]
    case .threeMonths:
        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "dd MMM"
        let offset = Double(-15*24*60*60)
        let start = Date()
        let fifthString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset))
        let fourthString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 2))
        let thirdString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 3))
        let secondString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 4))
        let firstString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 5))

        return[firstString, secondString, thirdString, fourthString, fifthString, ""]
    case .oneYear:
        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "MMM"
        let offset = Double(-80*24*60*60)
        let start = Date()
        let fifthString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset))
        let fourthString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 2))
        let thirdString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 3))
        let secondString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 4))
        let firstString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 5))

        return[firstString, secondString, thirdString, fourthString, fifthString, ""]

    case .fiveYears:
        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy"
        let offset = Double(-365*24*60*60)
        let start = Date()
        let fifthString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset))
        let fourthString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 2))
        let thirdString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 3))
        let secondString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 4))
        let firstString = fmt.string(from: start.addingTimeInterval(offset * 5))

        return[firstString, secondString, thirdString, fourthString, fifthString, ""]
    }
    return []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 2, date components in `NSDateComponents` were
represented as `Int`, and undefined components were set to the special value `NSDateComponentUndefined`.

In Swift 3, date components in `DateComponents` are represented as
optionals (`Int?`)  and undefined components are `nil`.

So `weekday` in your code is an optional and you need to unwrap it
(which is safe because you *requested* that component):

```
switch weekday! {
case 1:
    // ...
}
```

Or you can match against the "optional pattern":

```
switch weekday {
case 1?:
    // ...
}
```

(Apparently Xcode "Fix-it" does not work correctly, it suggests
`case ?1:` instead of `case 1?:`. This happens in both Xcode 8
and Xcode 9 and looks like a bug.)

*However, an easier solution* is to use the
[`component(_:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293299-component)
method of `Calendar`:

```
let weekday = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).component(.weekday, from: Date())
```

which gives you a single date component as a (non-optional) `Int`.
Note that the cast to `NSCalendar` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here the error occurs because the variable `weekday` is a optional one and you are using that in the switch case statement. You can either provide a default value for `weekday` or force unwrap it before using in switch case statement.

```
let weekday = (Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian) as NSCalendar).components(.weekday, from: Date()).weekday ?? 0
```

here you are providing `0` as default value to `weekday`. Or you can use

```
let weekday = (Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian) as NSCalendar).components(.weekday, from: Date()).weekday
   switch weekday! {
   case 1:
   .....
}
```